# Display error message for a textbox on blur

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I'm brand new to javascript and knockout. I'm working on client side validation using knockout-validation and am having some trouble. I want textboxes that require some user input to show their error messages on blur (even if the user didn't enter anything). A problem I ran into is that I don't want the error messages to show up right away. I was able to get this working but was wondering if someone had a more elegant way to do this. The pseudo code for what I do is set a textbox's value as an observable and then subscribe that to hasfocus of the textbox. Here is the sample code of the view model and the fiddle to go with it:

```
self.firstName = ko.observable().extend({
    required: true,
    notify: 'always'
});

self.firstName.focused = ko.observable();

self.firstName.focused.subscribe(function(newVal) {
    if(not the first time in the function and the value hasn't changed)
    {
        update the value to itself;
        //if this is empty then it will trigger the "required" error message
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sderico/qAnxw/

I want to know if there's a nicer way to implement this functionality (or any other ways that aren't too convoluted). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to specify the [`valueUpdate` option](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html) to `'blur'` on in your `value` binding. Then knockout will also update the value of `firstName` on the blur event which triggers the validation:

```
<input type="text" runat="server" ID="FirstName" 
       data-bind="value: firstName, valueUpdate: 'blur'"/>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/myppN/).

Comment: That's much nicer. Thanks!

Comment: Found a little bug (well not really since this does what I asked) where if you enter valid text and press enter to try to submit the form this textbox is in then an invalid message will pop up. I think I may be able to do something like bind valueUpdate: {'blur', 'submit'} so I'll try that out.